# Overriding TwoWayRule for in-place element swapping

Tags: replacement, rule

I'd like to make `\[TwoWayRule]` work for things other than graph edges, for example, for swapping i.e. Replace, ReplaceAll, StringReplace, etc:

```
{1,2,3} /. 1 <-> 2
StringReplace["a b c", "a" <-> "b"]
```

Unfortunately, `Replace` and friends are kernel functions, and I don't want to break anything accidentally. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I don't *think* this will break anything:

```
Unprotect[TwoWayRule];
TwoWayRule /: ReplaceAll[a_, TwoWayRule[x_, y_]] := 
    ReplaceAll[a, {x -> y, y -> x}]
Protect@TwoWayRule
```

Here you are adding an `UpValue` to `TwoWayRule` which is much safer than adding a `DownValue` to `ReplaceAll`.

```
{1, 2, 3} /. 1 <-> 2
(* {2, 1, 3} *)
```

Note that this is a very limited definition, it won't cover cases where you have a list of replacement rules.